# Failed matching mocking signature with UByteArray but not with ByteArray

Tags: kotlin, mockk

When mocking the following interface:

```kotlin
interface MyDescriptor {
    fun receive(): UByteArray
    fun send(bytes: UByteArray)
}
```

with the following test code:

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun send_oneMessage(): Unit = runBlocking {
        val byteStream = mockk<MyDescriptor>()
        every { byteStream.send(any()) } just Runs
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
io.mockk.MockKException: Failed matching mocking signature for
SignedCall(retValue=, isRetValueMock=true, retType=class kotlin.Unit, self=MyDescriptor(#1), method=send-GBYM_sE(ByteArray), args=[null], invocationStr=MyDescriptor(#1).send-GBYM_sE(null))
left matchers: [any()]
```

Now, if instead of `any()` I use an actual `UByteArray`, it runs:

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun send_oneMessage(): Unit = runBlocking {
        val payload = "Payload message"
        val byteStream = mockk<MyDescriptor>()
        every { byteStream.send(payload.toByteArray().toUByteArray()) } just Runs
    }
```

I can't help but to notice this part of the error: `method=send-GBYM_sE(ByteArray), args=[null]`, which mentions a `ByteArray` and not a `UByteArray`, like if it was looking for the wrong function signature (hence the error), but I can't understand why. Changing `any()` for `any<UByteArray>()` results in the same error, as does using `ofType(UByteArray::class)`...

However, it works with `ByteArray` instead of `UByteArray`:

```kotlin
interface MyDescriptor {
    fun receive(): UByteArray
    fun send(bytes: ByteArray)
}
```

Am I missing something?

Note: the error is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68904766/io-mockk-mockkexception-failed-matching-mocking-signature-for-signedcall), but my test code is fairly different, hence the new question.

Comment: Unsigned types are not currently supported by MockK, there's an open issue about that: https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/544

Comment: Oh right! I think that would be a valid answer then :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsigned types are not currently supported by MockK, there's an [open issue](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/544) about that.