# Failed matching mocking signature for SignedCall Mockk

Tags: android, static, mockk

I have a class that I recently converted from java to kotlin and now one of my unit tests is failing to compile.

This is line that is causing it:

```
    mockkStatic(PhoneNumberSelectionActivity::class)
    every {
        PhoneNumberSelectionActivity.startActivity(
            mockActivity,
            any(),
            any()
        )
    } returns Unit
```

My stack trace:

> Failed matching mocking signature for
> SignedCall(retValue=java.lang.Void@7a5aa8c5, isRetValueMock=false, retType=class java.lang.Void, self=TNActivityBase(mockActivity#1), method=startActivity(Intent), args=[null], invocationStr=TNActivityBase(mockActivity#1).startActivity(null))
> left matchers: [any(), any()]

> io.mockk.MockKException: Failed matching mocking signature for
> SignedCall(retValue=java.lang.Void@7a5aa8c5, isRetValueMock=false, retType=class java.lang.Void, self=TNActivityBase(mockActivity#1), method=startActivity(Intent), args=[null], invocationStr=TNActivityBase(mockActivity#1).startActivity(null))
> left matchers: [any(), any()]

The class PhoneNumberSelectionActivity inherits from TNActivityBase.

Here is the function that we are trying to mock in PhoneNumberSelectionActivity:

```
    fun startActivity(
        host: Activity,
        phoneExpired: Boolean,
        @ACTIVITY_HOST_TYPE activityHostType: Int
    ) {
        if (sIsRunning) {
            return
        }
        sIsRunning = true
        val intent = Intent(host, PhoneNumberSelectionActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ACTIVITY_HOST_TYPE, activityHostType)
        if (phoneExpired) {
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_PHONE_EXPIRE_DIALOG, true)
        }
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
        host.startActivity(intent)
    }
```

It seems to me that mockkStatic is not doing its job.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently unsigned types are not supported in Mockk.

[Failed matching mocking signature with UByteArray but not with ByteArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69353595/failed-matching-mocking-signature-with-ubytearray-but-not-with-bytearray)

So I did:

```
    every {
        PhoneNumberSelectionActivity.startActivity(
            mockActivity,
            true,
            PhoneNumberSelectionActivity.ACTIVITY_HOST_TYPE.AUTHORIZATION
        )
    } returns Unit
```