# How can I mock a call to Spring's repository `saveAll()` method using mockk?

Tags: kotlin, mocking, mockito, mockk, spring-repositories

I am using `Mockk` as my mocking framework when testing my Spring Boot Data repository interfaces.

Actually I am doing the following

```
every { itemRepository.saveAll(listOf(any(), any())) } returns listOf<Item>(mockk())
```

which should mock the following behaviour

```
val loot: List<Item> = itemGenerator.generateLoot(lootTable)
itemRepository.saveAll(loot)
```

The error message I receive is the following:

```
Failed matching mocking signature for
SignedCall(retValue=, isRetValueMock=true, retType=class kotlin.collections.Iterable, self=ItemRepository(#28), method=saveAll(Iterable), args=[[com.barbarus.gameserver.item.Item@ea00de, com.barbarus.gameserver.item.Item@23ca36d]], invocationStr=ItemRepository(#28).saveAll([com.barbarus.gameserver.item.Item@ea00de, com.barbarus.gameserver.item.Item@23ca36d]))
left matchers: [any(), any()]
```

The error message says `left matchers: [any(), any()]` pointing out that I somehow am not defining the expected arguments right.

I could fully define the items by real implementations in my test logic but I'd like to stick with `mockk()` just to keep the test code slim and fast.

However I kinda am not able to define the `List<Item>` with two elements using `listOf(any(),any())` here. I tried other API of Mockk without any luck.

Any idea what to use in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You should type the `any()` when you are passing into `saveAll()`.

For instance:

```
import com.barbarus.gameserver.item.Item
...

every { itemRepository.saveAll(any<List<Item>>() } returns listOf<Item>(mockk())
```

[Solution from another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72552385)